# Prisma append custom field to info argument when querying data

Tags: graphql, prisma

I am trying to append extra fields to the info object when querying data from prisma database. I have seen this [post](https://www.prisma.io/forum/t/append-to-info-to-get-additional-fields-back/3972) but I can't get fragments working.

I have below migrations:

```
type User {
 id: ID! @unique
 name: String
}

type Video {
 id: ID! @unique
 name: String
 likes: [Like]
}

type Like {
 id: ID! @unique
 user: User
 createdAt: DateTime!
}
```

Now, I would like to query all videos and check if current user has already liked a video. If so, the likes object should read the createdAt value, otherwise it would be empty.

I am doing this in playground via following query:

```
query {
 videos() {
  id
  name
  hasVoted: likes(where: {user: {id: "cjr7r85jy00rc0892dfwpu96u"}){
   createdAt
  }
 }
}
```

this works but I would like to add the hasVoted to my query resolver to automatically append it to all queries. How can I do this ?

I tried solving it via fragments but without luck:

```
        videos: {
          fragment: `fragment hasVoted on Video { 
            hasVoted: likes (where: {user: {id: "cjr7r85jy00rc0892dfwpu96u"}}){
              createdAt
            }
           }`,
          resolve: async (_, args, ctx, info) => {
            return await ctx.prisma.query.videos({},info);
          }
        }
```

Anyone has some ideas how I can do this?  thx!

Comment: Are you using the Prisma client or `prisma-binding`?

Comment: Hey:) I am using **prisma-binding**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use addFragmentToInfo from graphql-bindings

https://oss.prisma.io/content/graphql-binding/02-api-reference#addfragmenttoinfo